# Declare an array that exists inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I always declare my array... good practice, I guess. Like so:

```
$image_rows = [];
```

But, am I being to picky by also declaring an array that exists inside a `foreach` loop. If I do declare it, are there any negatives?

```
$image_rows = [];
$vrow = [];

foreach($image_rows as $vrow) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that’s entirely superfluous.

Comment: That's a good practice. Make sure you are not overwriting the array.

Comment: @still They are by necessity overwriting it in `as $vrow`…!

Comment: @deceze `$vrow = ['1','2']; $vrow = []; print_r($vrow);` this is what i meant by overriting.

Comment: @still Sure, but that’s implicitly going to happen here with the loop anyway.

Comment: Nope if you overrite the array with blank array, then nothing matters afterwards. @deceze

Answer (score 1):

This would only make sense if you need `$vrow` after the loop to hold the last iteration’s value, and there’s a chance `$image_rows` may be empty, and you’re thus establishing a default value.

It has absolutely no use whatsoever if `$vrow` is supposed to be used inside the loop only. The potential harm here would be that by declaring it outside the loop, you’re implying a different use case to future readers of this code. Also, should you accidentally (or as a consequence of confusing yourself with your own implications) refer to `$vrow` after the loop, your IDE and/or PHP won’t give you a warning and just let you continue working with what’s probably the wrong value.